# Link to blank page and addition new condition in php code

Tags: php, html, joomla

I'd like to add condition to my code so that after click on label it link me to other page. Now this code link to other article on the website. So I guess what should I add to get from my label to other page.

Thank you for answers!
My code is below:

```
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs aboutUsTabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <?php foreach ($this->items as $key=>$item ){ 

       if($item['children']){ ?>
          <li role="presentation" class="<?php if($item['menu']->id==$this->pageId || $item['menu']->id==$this->parentId){ echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="#about-us-page-<?php echo $item['menu']->id;?>" aria-controls="about-us-page-<?php echo $item['menu']->id;?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $item['menu']->title;?></a></li>

      <?php }else{ ?>
              <li role="presentation" class="<?php if($item['menu']->id==$this->pageId || $item['menu']->id==$this->parentId){ echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="<?php echo $item['menu']->path;?>" aria-controls="about-us-page-<?php echo $item['menu']->id;?>"><?php echo $item['menu']->title;?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Might I suggest cleaning up your code, so you don't switch between PHP and HTML constantly? https://pastebin.com/7FKiFaKp

Answer (score 1):

All this start/stop of PHP code hurts my eyes! Anyways, linking to other pages is done with `<a href=""></a>` tags. Not quite sure I understand your question, but you could (if you mean labels for form elements) do something like this;

```
<label for=""> <a href="SOME_PAGE.html"> Something Meaningful </a> </label>
```

I'm sorry, but I took the liberty to clean up your code a little. Hopefully this will make it more readable;

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs aboutUsTabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
<?php 

foreach ($this->items as $key=>$item ){ 

    $active = NULL;
    if($item['menu']->id==$this->pageId || $item['menu']->id==$this->parentId){ 
        $active = 'active';
    }

    $menu = NULL;
    if($item['menu']->id==$this->pageId || $item['menu']->id==$this->parentId){ 
        $menu = 'active'; 
    }

    if($item['children']){ 
        echo'<li role="presentation" class="'.$active.'">
                <a href="#about-us-page-'.$item['menu']->id.'" aria-controls="about-us-page-'.$item['menu']->id.'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'.$item['menu']->title.'</a>
            </li>';

    }else{ 
        echo'<li role="presentation" class="'.$menu.'">
                <a href="'.$item['menu']->path.'" aria-controls="about-us-page-'.$item['menu']->id.'">'.$item['menu']->title.'</a>
            </li>';
    }
} 

?>
</ul>
```

For your comment question, if you know what item needs a different value, it could be the `title` f.ex. then you can check against that value and change the output of your element. Maybe something like;

```
if($item['children']){ 

    if($item['title'] == 'Unique Identifier for your element') {
        // In here you could manipulate the output of that one item you want to exclude/change

    } else { 
        // Your normal output
        echo'<li role="presentation" class="'.$active.'">
                    <a href="#about-us-page-'.$item['menu']->id.'" aria-controls="about-us-page-'.$item['menu']->id.'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'.$item['menu']->title.'</a>
                </li>';

}else{ ... }
```

And even better would be to perform the check beforehand, so maybe something like;

```
$link = '#about-us-page-'.$item['menu']->id;
if($item['title'] == "That identifier") {
    $link = 'somethingElse';
}
```

and then change the value of your `href` tag to;

```
 <a href="'.$link.'" aria-controls="about-us-page-'.$item['menu']->id.'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'.$item['menu']->title.'</a>
```

Comment: First condition if  refers to all labels on the page and after click appropriate label website link to exactly article which is on page. I'd like to do an exception for one label, and this label should not show me article on the page but take me to separate website. I don't know how to refer to this one label in php code. That's my problem. Now is it more clear for you?

Comment: Is there a unique identifier for that one label you want to exclude? Maybe the `['title']` - if so, you could perform something like  a `if` statement to change the output. Something like `if($item['menu']->title == 'The Item You'd Like Excluded') { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: I like your cleaned code, I don't have an answer for the question but I have also cleaned up the code, as the following: https://pastebin.com/7FKiFaKp

Comment: all these opening and closing tags are pretty standard in many templating systems, like ones from Wordpress or Joomla, they open and close at each line.. totally agree with you, most of the time ugly and quite useless..

Comment: And where in code above you'd place the exception. It can be example of course.

Comment: Where can I find id or name? My labels has the same class.

Comment: You are working with these items; `$this->items as $key=>$item` (check your `foreach` loop). It seems that these `items` you are working with both hold a  `$item['id']` and `$item['name']` - that is where I got the id and name. Now the items you want to manipulate probably hold a unique value for one of these two variables, so you can change the output by looking for  something unique in the item(s) you'd like to change.